# Is the phrase "Traffic Revision" generally used to describe temporary or permanent changes of traffic flow?

Tags: differences, expressions

When I first moved to Washington state, I would see mystifying traffic warning signs that would announce "Traffic Revision Ahead" as I was driving and then be in the midst of roadwork and lane changes a few seconds later.

I don't recall exactly what signs said in my home state of Nebraska for this situation but I think they would post a sequence of signs, a "Roadwork Ahead" followed by a "Lane Changes Necessary" indication.  Either that or a display of "Detour Ahead" before the work.

Once I understood by context what I was in for when I saw such signs, I used to imagine a civil engineer sitting at a desk thinking "I have a vision; No... I have a revision".

Is this usage of "Traffic Revision" known anywhere else in the English speaking world, or is this a coinage specific to  Washington state in the United States?

Comment: I would expect a sign that says "New Traffic Pattern Ahead," but I do most of my driving in the Northeast U.S.

Comment: I like that expression much more than "Traffic Revision", which I find to be extremely obtuse and confusing. When I first saw Washington's signs I couldn't imagine in what sense traffic could be revised. That confusion led to several terrifying driving moments until I caught on.

Comment: I have never encountered "revision" in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I have never encountered any such sign, but then I didn't drive a lot in the US or UK. It's definitely not specific to Washington, as evidenced by [this picture](http://www.flickr.com/photos/toddmecklem/5154275774/) from Oregon and another one from [Vancouver](http://www.flickr.com/photos/arthaey/3873196492/in/set-72157622066263041/).

Comment: Thanks, F'x. Now I wonder if this is a Northwest phenomena. Also wonder which locale first used the term in signage.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, "New Road Layout Ahead" seems to be universal.  It might even enshrined in some obscure law, I know a lot of road signs are.

[image: New Road Layout Ahead]